# How to show states of a country map while using rnaturalearth package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If one uses the `sp` package, `sp::plot(ne_states(country = "spain"))` shows a Spain map in which states of the country are rendered. However, if the `sp` package is not used, say,

```
ne_countries(scale = 10, returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  filter(geounit == "Spain") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

how can one get the same result? If I do

```
ne_states(scale = 10, returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  filter(geounit == "Spain") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Error in ne_states(scale = 10, returnclass = "sf") : 
  unused argument (scale = 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `ne_states` has no `scale` argument. Besides that it's basically the same for `sf` as for `sp` except for the different `returnclass`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(rnaturalearth)
#> Warning: package 'rnaturalearth' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Support for Spatial objects (`sp`) will be deprecated in {rnaturalearth} and will be removed in a future release of the package. Please use `sf` objects with {rnaturalearth}. For example: `ne_download(returnclass = 'sf')`

ne_states(country = "Spain", returnclass = "sf") |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]